# onclick inside iframe for a button outside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to find a way to initiate an `onclick` inside an iframe when a button outside the iframe is clicked.

The code for the `onclick` is included below.

```
<div style='float: right;'>
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick ='xnaww_download()' data-tooltip-ul="Download map data of a selected region. Output data is in KML format">
</div>
```

Comment: What does the code from within the iframe look like?

Comment: That is the code for the onclick insise the iframe

Comment: Cleaned up question and code to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the following script from the parent page (assuming you are using jQuery and the id of the iFrame is "iframeElement"):

```
 $("#iframeElement")[0].contentWindow.xnaww_download();
```

**This will only work as long as the parent and frame are on the same domain.  Otherwise you'll run into cross-domain-scripting errors!**

Comment: should be noted that this only works if both parent and frame are on the same domain.